# Multiple Audio on DELL Laptop

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Explanation would be much appreciated!...
Yesterday I managed to play two Albums simultaneously, one using Amazon Music through my bluetooth headphones and the other using iTunes through the laptop speaker. This wasn't my aim at the time, but I'm assuming the fact that it was possible might offer some explanation of why I couldn't get the iTune Album to play over the bluetooth connection.
Inexplicably, today, I have been able to get the iTunes output to go to the bluetooth headphones! In fact I am now able to listen to both audios on the headphones simultaneously! So does anyone know what's going on?